# Python: Sort Nested List of Strings and Numbers by Multiple Columns in Different Orders

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

Given a nested list like

```py
a = [["a", "z"], ["b", "y"], ["c", "x"], ["d", "x"], ["e", "x"]]

# should output
a = [['e', 'x'], ['d', 'x'], ['c', 'x'], ['b', 'y'], ['a', 'z']]
```

How would I sort this by the second column in ascending order, then by the first column in descending order if duplicates occur with only one sort?

I am basically trying to achieve something like SQL's SORT BY col1 ASC, col2 DESC, col3 ASC ...

I could do something like
`sorted(sorted(a, key=lambda x:(x[1])), key=lambda x:(x[0]), reverse=True)` but I'm wondering if there is a better and simpler way of achieving this.

Comment: `sorted(a, key=lambda x: [x[1], [-ord(x) for x in x[0]]])` works in one pass using the ordinal value of each character in `x` but it's a bit ugly and the list comprehension seems slow. If there's a comparable value for a string that `x[0]` can be fed into, that'd be better.

Comment: @ggorlen would interpreting the first column as a hex number work as replacement to the list comprehension? ```sorted(a, key=lambda x: [x[1], -int(x[0].encode('utf-8').hex())])```

Comment: @Kevin Interesting idea, thanks. That seems like it'd work but the problem is, if the strings are really long, the `int` call creates a big number that probably winds up looking like an array internally, so I'm not sure if it's an improvement. The code isn't really any more readable either. I'm still hoping for a single library function call that makes a string comparable, but maybe this doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x: (x[1], [-ord(x) for x in x[0]]))
```

This works in one pass on strings of any length. The idea is to use the ordinal value of each character in `x` as the second element in the `key` comparator. Unary `-` inverts the values, giving the desired reversed ordering.

Comment: I think using tuples instead of lists as the ```key``` is preferred here due to immutability?

Comment: In general yes, but it doesn't really matter here because we're returning the list to the library immediately, so there's no chance of us somehow mutating it in the lambda. Updated nonetheless!

Comment: I see. But I believe that the construction time for tuples will be faster, due to it not over-allocating. But this kind of optimization might be negligible also.

Comment: You'd have to profile/benchmark it but it seems spurious.

Answer (score -1):

You can specify both conditions in the return value of your lambda

```
>>> a = [["a", "z"], ["b", "y"], ["c", "x"], ["d", "x"], ["e", "x"]]
>>> sorted(a, key = lambda x: (x[1], -1 * ord(x[0])))
[['e', 'x'], ['d', 'x'], ['c', 'x'], ['b', 'y'], ['a', 'z']]
>>>
```

To extend the behavior to general keys define your own functions to calculate the value of a key and provide those in lambda. Please see below.
Those functions can be as simple or as complicated as you like.
Think of them similar to comprator functions you provide to quicksort library, but instead of -1,+1,0 you return an absolute value for the key which Python will use to sort.

```
>>> def first_key(x):
...     return x
... 
>>> def second_key(x):
...     return -1 * ord(x)
... 
>>> sorted(a, key = lambda x: (first_key(x[1]), second_key(x[0])))
[['e', 'x'], ['d', 'x'], ['c', 'x'], ['b', 'y'], ['a', 'z']]
>>> a
[['a', 'z'], ['b', 'y'], ['c', 'x'], ['d', 'x'], ['e', 'x']]
>>>
```

Comment: This doesn't handle multi-character strings. My solution in the comments seems safer and more robust. You can use it if you want. Almost certainly, these single-character strings are placeholders for more realistic strings. `-ord(x[0])` is cleaner than `-1 * ord(x[0])`.

Comment: ggorlen is correct in that I did intend to use it on longer strings but the use of separate functions to give values to keys witha more correct answer could solve this problem.